# Anomaly with a pdf

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

The pdf of the  range  $\omega$ of $n$  identically r.v.'s  random variables  distributed with cdf $\mathbf{F}$  and pdf $\mathbf{f}$   is given by
$$  g(\omega)=n(n-1) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)[F(x+\omega)-F(x)]^{n-2} f(x+\omega) dx$$
Now Consider the pdf
$$ f(x)=2x,\,0 \leq x \leq1 $$. and the corresponding cdf
$$F(x)=x^2,0 \leq  x\leq 1,1 \text{else}$$
This means the pdf of the range of the given sequence of $n$   random variables   should be given by :
$$ g(\omega)=4 n(n-1) \int_0^1 x(x+\omega)[(x+\omega)^2-x^2]^{n-2}\, dx$$
How can I verify that  $g$ as a function of $\omega$ is indeed a probability density function.It appears $\omega $ will vary from 0 to 1.  is When I solve the integral and take the integral of $g(\omega )$ from 0 to 1 I am not getting 1,which has to be the case if $g$ is indeed a pdf.  Even for $n=2$ we obtain
$$g(\omega)= 8 \int _0^1 (x^2+x \omega) dx= \frac83+\frac{\omega}{2}$$,which is not a pdf for $\omega $ in the $(0,1)$
I would be most obliged if somebody can help me fix any  errors with the help of  Mathematica  or some other CAS .Thanking you in advance

Comment: I have problems with the formulation of your problem. Initially you assume r.v. on $\mathbb{R}$ (terms pdf and cdf). But in the next sentence you assume that the random variables have values in the unit circle $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon x_1^2+x_2^2 \leq 1\}$ (two dimensional).

Comment: @DieterKadelka there is no problem with the formulation of the problem .though the point s pie in  the unit circle ,I am only interested  in the distribution of their radial distances and radial distance  is one dimensional variable.I have also explicitly mentioned the pdf ,which is in terms of a single variable .Hope this answers your query

Comment: O.K., it seems that the introduction is simply motivation, but has nothing to do with your problem. If I understand correctly you simply have $n$ independent r.v. $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ with pdf $f$, But what is then formally "the range of radial distances of n random points"?

Comment: I am applying the formula for range to  the radial distances of $n$ independently ,uniformly and randomly  points in  unit circle and  what i get seems not to make sense .When I do a sanity test whether the 'pdf' so obtained is really a pdf,  we find that the function does not satisfy the conditions of a pdf. the axample i am taking is not meant for motivation only,it is my real question and the thing I want some help about

Comment: Again, you even calculated that $g$ is no pdf. It is completely irrelevant how you get the integral. There must be something wrong with $g$! So again what is formally "the range of radial distances of n random points"?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using incorrect expressions for the pdf $g$ of the range, and for the cdf $F$ and pdf $f$ of the radial distance. (Also, it is not good to denote a random variable (r.v.) and its values by the same symbol (in your case, $\omega$). Also, there is no reason to use the Greek letter $\omega$ if you can use (say) $t$ instead -- which is what we are going to do.)

Now, a correct expression for the pdf $g$ of the range $R:=\max_{1\le i\le n}X_i-\min_{1\le i\le n}X_i$ is given by
$$g(t)=h(t):=n(n-1)\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)[F(x+t)-F(x)]^{n-2} f(x+t)\, dx\;1(t>0) $$
for real $t$, where $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent r.v.'s with common cdf $F$ and pdf $f$; your expression is missing the factor $1(t>0)$.

The function $h$ is a pdf, because it is the pdf of the range $R$.

Another way to check that $h$ is a pdf is to note that (i) $h$ is obviously nonnegative and (ii)
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t)\,dt \\ 
=n(n-1)\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\,f(x)\int_0^\infty dt\,[F(x+t)-F(x)]^{n-2} f(x+t) \\ 
=n(n-1)\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\,f(x)\frac{[F(x+t)-F(x)]^{n-1}}{n-1}\Big|_{t=0}^\infty \\ =n\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\,f(x)[1-F(x)]^{n-1}
=-[1-F(x)]^n\Big|_{x=-\infty}^\infty=1. \tag{1}$$

---

In your case, correct expressions for the cdf $F$ and pdf $f$ of the radial distance are given by formulas
$$F(x)=x^2\,1(0<x<1)+1(x\ge1)$$
(rather than $F(x)=x^2$) and
$$f(x)=2x\,1(0<x<1)$$
(rather than $f(x)=2x$), where $x$ is any real number.
So, your (incorrect) formula
$$ g(\omega)=4 n(n-1) \int_0^1 x(x+\omega)[(x+\omega)^2-x^2]^{n-2}\, dx$$
should be replaced by
$$g(t)=4 n(n-1)\int_0^1 x(x+t)1(x+t<1)[(x+t)^2\,1(x+t<1)+1(x+t\ge1)-x^2]^{n-2}\, dx\,1(t>0).$$
However, there is no need to repeat (1) for your particular $F$ and $f$.

Comment: @losif Pinelis I am so thankful to you for pointing out  the fatal mistake in my approach.So kind o you for taking time

Comment: @losif Pnielis but i faiil to see how that will change $g(t)$ ..$F(x+t)=F(x)$ outside $(0,1)$.Could you please clarify?

Comment: @sajjadveeri : I have added the correct expression for $g(t)$ in your case. There is no need to use it, though.